# htaccess RewriteRule doesnt load js-css libraries

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess

I use  htaccess file for pretty url in my php site.
htaccess file is in below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?mod=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I write the URL like 127.0.0.1/mysite/param1, it means;
127.0.0.1/mysite/index.php?mod=param1 and page loads without any problem.

But, when I write the URL 127.0.0.1/mysite/param1**/**, the css and js files dont load on the page. Because my css and js files are in the inc/ directory and the path changes . The path turns this:
param1/inc/jsfile.js

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using relative links for your assets. Add this code to your `head` section in your html.

```
<base href="http://domain.com/mysite/" />
```

Or you can add a leading `/` to your paths like so.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/style.css">
```

updated since you're using it in a subfolder.

Comment: It's also often used to load the the CSS / JavaScript files with the full url, e.g. `example.org/mysite/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Panama Jack and Kneecht,  your answers are helpful.

Firstly; I used `<base>` tag. But still didnt work although the paths was correct. I checked on chrome, js and css files succesfuly opened in a new tab when I clicked on it in source code, but they didnt affected the page. I didnt solve it,  I think the problem was  cache memory or something like that .

So I tried the other solution: full path of file.

I defined the base url on the top of the index.php file and I used it whenever I need it:

```
define("BASE", "http://127.0.0.1/mysite/");

<link href="<?php echo constant("BASE") ?>inc/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This works.